# Modifying objects in an array with same name

Tags: python, arrays, list, object

I have below array:

```
object['table.column_values'] =
[
 {'name1': '10.1.10.1', 'name2': '100~200', 'name3': ''}, 
 {'name1': '2.2.2.2', 'name2': '', 'name3': '>1024'}, 
 {'name1': '1.1.1.1', 'name2': '', 'name3': 'nam3'}
]
```

I want to add the word `column-` to all keys like below:

```
[
 {'column-name1': '10.1.10.1', 'column-name2': '100~200', 'column-name3': ''}, 
 {'column-name1': '2.2.2.2', 'column-name2': '', 'column-name3': '>1024'}, 
 {'column-name1': '1.1.1.1', 'column-name2': '', 'column-name3': 'nam3'}
]
```

for that, I use this algorithm:

```
for value_count in range(len(object['table.column_values'])):
   for item in object['table.column_values'][value_count]:
      edited_item = 'column-' + item 
      row_values[edited_item] = object['table.column_values'][value_count][item]

    all_values.append(row_values)
```

but it gives me an array with duplicated objects of last object:

```
[
 {'column-name1': '1.1.1.1', 'column-name2': '', 'column-name3': 'nam3'}, 
 {'column-name1': '1.1.1.1', 'column-name2': '', 'column-name3': 'nam3'}, 
 {'column-name1': '1.1.1.1', 'column-name2': '', 'column-name3': 'nam3'}
]
```

Is there a way in python to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested list/dictionary comprehension to add `column-` to all the key names:

```py
result = [ { f'column-{k}' : v for k, v in d.items() } for d in object['table.column_values'] ]
```

Output:

```
[
 {'column-name1': '10.1.10.1', 'column-name2': '100~200', 'column-name3': ''},
 {'column-name1': '2.2.2.2', 'column-name2': '', 'column-name3': '>1024'},
 {'column-name1': '1.1.1.1', 'column-name2': '', 'column-name3': 'nam3'}
]
```

Comment: How concise and useful.. Thank you

Comment: @ShokouhDareshiri no worries - I'm glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
data = [
 {'name1': '10.1.10.1', 'name2': '100~200', 'name3': ''}, 
 {'name1': '2.2.2.2', 'name2': '', 'name3': '>1024'}, 
 {'name1': '1.1.1.1', 'name2': '', 'name3': 'nam3'}
]

new_data = [{"column-" + key: value for key, value in dic.items()} for dic in data]
print()
```

Comment: How concise and useful.. Thank you